# Confirm delete before deleting dataview's row

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html

I have a GridView which supports deleting. I'd like to add a pop up window with a question like 'Are you sure you want to delete this row?'.

My code:

```
<asp:GridView id="GridAccounts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        ShowFooter="True" DataKeyNames="ID" 
        DataSourceID="AccountDataSource" onrowcommand="GridAccounts_RowCommand">
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Lime" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" ShowDeleteButton="True" DeleteImageUrl="~/Pictures/delete.jpg" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="ID">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelAccountIDUpdate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonAccountIDInsert" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                </FooterTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelAccountID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void GridPaymentMethod_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            ImageButton deleteButton = (ImageButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
            MyMoney.PaymentMethodRow row = (MyMoney.PaymentMethodRow)((System.Data.DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
            deleteButton.OnClientClick = string.Format("return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete payment method {0}?');", row.Name.Replace("'", @"\'"));
        }
    }
```

This renders as:

```
<input type="image" src="Pictures/delete.jpg" alt="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete payment method Gotovina?');javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$GridPaymentMethod','Delete$0')" style="border-width:0px;" />
```

If I click OK on confirmation window, postback occurs, but nothing happens. If I comment out RowDataBound code, than delete works OK. Code whithout confirmation pop up:

```
<input type="image" src="Pictures/delete.jpg" alt="Delete" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$GridPaymentMethod','Delete$0')" style="border-width:0px;" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you must change ButtonType="Image" to ButtonType="Link" - then onclick="..." will be rendered without javascript:___doPostBack(...) part. And in the GridPaymentMethod_RowDataBound event set something like deleteButton.Text = "<img src=\"path_to_image\" ... />" (use html entities instead of <>).

Or you can use ImageButton with ComamndName="delete" and [ConfirmButtonExtender](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ConfirmButton/ConfirmButton.aspx) from ASP.NET AjaxToolkit suite.

Answer (score 3):

I believe [this](http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/fritz/archive/2006/03/22/20514.aspx) is an example of what you are trying to do. It's cleaner and you don't have to go nutz with the code behind.

Comment: Quite. There's nothing magical about a CommandField - it just adds a standard LinkButton with a CommandName set to the action you want to launch. You can just replace it with your own LinkButton with the correct CommandName (eg. CommandName="Delete" would trigger delete event).

Answer (score 0):

```
deleteButton.OnClientClick = string.Format("((!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete payment method {0}?'))?return false);", row.Name.Replace("'", @"\'"));
```